# How can I write a script to keep HSQLDB running in case the process is killed

Tags: linux, process, hsqldb

I'm running HSQLDB in server mode on a Linux server and finding that it occasionally gets killed.  I'd like to be able to detect that it's stopped running and then kick off a process that starts it up again.

The DB isn't running very often, so polling would have to be very frequent--once every five minutes.

Comment: Maybe it would be better, to find out why the DB gets killed and fix this issue, rather than to throw more tools around it. I'd start with  `hsqldb.applog`, "The default level 0 indicates no logging. Level 1 results in events related to persistence to be logged, including any failures. The events are logged in a file ending with .app.log", see: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html

Comment: @The MY YN HSQLDB applog is useful for monitoring database operations and will contain an entry if the database was shutdown with an SQL command. But it will never contain a specific entry if the process was killed because of a JVM crash or other causes on the server. In any case, an HSQLDB server never kills itself unless a SHUTDOWN statement is performed on the last database it is serving.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/):

> Monit is a free open source utility for managing and monitoring, processes, files, directories and filesystems on a UNIX system. Monit conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using soem type of Debian, you might try installing HSQLDB using "apt-get install hsqldb-server.  That will give you a nice install and the ability to start with "/etc/init.d/hsqldb-server start"

This will also take care of restarting it if your machine reboots.  If you get everything installed correctly the problem of it getting killed may just go away.

I was running into some weird issues starting and stopping hsqldb, but once I got it installed correctly everything took care of itself.